# Como remover um caractere específico de algumas strings específicas dentro de uma lista em Python?

Tags: python, string, lista, delete, caracteres

Eu tenho uma lista de exemplo:

```
['#[Header]', '#Application Name\tLCsolution', '#Version\t1.24']
```

Eu gostaria de saber como remover um caractere específico, como por exemplo, o `#` de todos os elementos da lista, ou, se eu preferir, de apenas alguns elementos, como `[0:1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o `replace` pra substituir os caracteres indesejados na sua string por uma string vazia:

```
'#[Header]'.replace('#', '')  # '[Header]'
```

Pra fazer isso em todas as strings da lista, basta usar uma compreensão de lista pra aplicar o `replace` em todos os elementos:

```
minha_lista = ['#[Header]', '#Application Name\tLCsolution', '#Version\t1.24']
minha_lista = [s.replace('#', '') for s in minha_lista]
```

Ou fazer o mesmo pra só um slice:

```
minha_lista = ['#[Header]', '#Application Name\tLCsolution', '#Version\t1.24']
minha_lista[:2] = [s.replace('#', '') for s in minha_lista[:2]]
```

Comment: E se eu quiser modificar os elementos da lista acessando o elemento pelo conteúdo deles?

Comment: @BrunoSantos pode dar um exemplo do que quer dizer?

Comment: lista_original = ['#flor', '#folha', '#pedra', '#arvore', '#tempestade']

Como eu removo o '#' de  '#pedra' e '#tempestade' sem saber o índice deles na lista? Apenas sabendo que eu quero alterar esses elementos, mesmo sem saber onde eles estão?

Comment: @BrunoSantos se entendi bem, é só fazer `minha_lista[minha_lista.index('#pedra')] = 'pedra'`, ou `minha_lista[minha_lista.index('#pedra')] = '#pedra'.replace('#', '')`.

Comment: obrigado!!!!!!!